# Flutter Xcode Build Error When I open a downloaded project

Tags: xcode, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-ios

I am trying to open flutter project which I've downloaded from some links. I need to make some configurations for my clients on their project but every time I attempt to open a project flutter and Xcode builds fail with really long error message. I tried all the solutions on web but still I am not able to compile these kind of projects. Your help is really appreciated. It took my long time but ı couldn't achieve what I want.

```
        objc[3966]: Class AMSupportURLConnectionDelegate is implemented in both ?? (0x1eb708188) and ?? (0x1139782b8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    objc[3966]: Class AMSupportURLSession is implemented in both ?? (0x1eb7081d8) and ?? (0x113978308). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    /Users/alperenbaskaya/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/in_app_review-2.0.2/ios/Classes/InAppReviewPlugin.m:99:14: warning: 'openURL:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS
    10.0 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
            [app openURL:url];
                 ^~~~~~~
                 openURL:options:completionHandler:
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/alperenbaskaya/AndroidStudioProjects/desio/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/in_app_review/in_app_review-prefix.pch:2:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIApplication.h:123:1:
    note: 'openURL:' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    - (BOOL)openURL:(NSURL*)url API_DEPRECATED_WITH_REPLACEMENT("openURL:options:completionHandler:", ios(2.0, 10.0)) NS_EXTENSION_UNAVAILABLE_IOS("");
    ^
    1 warning generated.
    /Users/alperenbaskaya/AndroidStudioProjects/desio/ios/Pods/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/Classes/WebSocket.m:111:11: warning: logical not is only applied to the left hand side of this
    comparison [-Wlogical-not-parentheses]
            else if (![upgradeHeaderValue caseInsensitiveCompare:@"WebSocket"] == NSOrderedSame) {
                     ^                                                         ~~
    /Users/alperenbaskaya/AndroidStudioProjects/desio/ios/Pods/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/Classes/WebSocket.m:111:11: note: add parentheses after the '!' to evaluate the comparison first
            else if (![upgradeHeaderValue caseInsensitiveCompare:@"WebSocket"] == NSOrderedSame) {
                     ^
                      (                                                                        )
    PAsyncFileResponse.m:216:57: warning: block implicitly retains 'self';
    explicitly mention 'self' to indicate this is intended behavior [-Wimplicit-retain-self]
                            HTTPLogError(@"%@: Read EOF on file(%@)", THIS_FILE, filePath);
                                                                                 ^
                                                                                 self->
    In file included from /Users/alperenbaskaya/AndroidStudioProjects/desio/ios/Pods/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/Classes/Responses/HTTPAsyncFileResponse.m:3:
    /Users/alperenbaskaya/AndroidStudioProjects/desio/ios/Pods/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/Classes/HTTPLogging.h:34:72: note: expanded from macro 'HTTPLogError'
    #define HTTPLogError(frmt, ...)    KTVCHSLog(HTTP_LOG_ERROR,   frmt, ##__VA_ARGS__)
                                                                           ^
    /Users/alperenbaskaya/AndroidStudioProjects/desio/ios/Pods/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/Classes/HTTPLogging.h:11:75: note: expanded from macro 'KTVCHSLog'
    #define KTVCHSLog(level, frmt, ...) [HTTPLogging log:level format:frmt, ##__VA_ARGS__]
                                                                              ^
    /Users/alperenbaskaya/AndroidStudioProjects/desio/ios/Pods/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/Classes/Responses/HTTPAsyncFileResponse.m:225:4: warning: block implicitly retains 'self';
    explicitly mention 'self' to indicate this is intended behavior [-Wimplicit-retain-self]
                            readOffset += result;
                            ^
                            self->
    /Users/alperenbaskaya/AndroidStudioProjects/desio/ios/Pods/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/Classes/Responses/HTTPAsyncFileResponse.m:226:4: warning: block implicitly retains 'self';
    explicitly mention 'self' to indicate this is intended behavior [-Wimplicit-retain-self]
                            readBufferOffset += result;
                            ^
                            self->
    20 warnings generated.
    /Users/alperenbaskaya/AndroidStudioProjects/desio/ios/Pods/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/Classes/WebSocket.m:111:11: warning: logical not is only applied to the left hand side of this
    comparison [-Wlogical-not-parentheses]
            else if (![upgradeHeaderValue caseInsensitiveCompare:@"WebSocket"] == NSOrderedSame) {
                     ^                                                         ~~
    /Users/alperenbaskaya/AndroidStudioProjects/desio/ios/Pods/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/Classes/WebSocket.m:111:11: note: add parentheses after the '!' to evaluate the comparison first
            else if (![upgradeHeaderValue caseInsensitiveCompare:@"WebSocket"] == NSOrderedSame) {
                     ^
                      (                                                                        )
    /Users/alperenbaskaya/AndroidStudioProjects/desio/ios/Pods/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/Classes/WebSocket.m:111:11: note: add parentheses around left hand side expression to silence
    this warning
            else if (![upgradeHeaderValue caseInsensitiveCompare:@"WebSocket"] == NSOrderedSame) {
                     ^
                     (                                                        )
    /Users/alperenbaskaya/AndroidStudioProjects/desio/ios/Pods/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/Classes/WebSocket.m:181:28: warning: sending 'WebSocket *__strong' to parameter of incompatible
    type 'id<GCDAsyncSocketDelegate> _Nullable'
                    [asyncSocket setDelegate:self delegateQueue:websocketQueue];
                                             ^~~~
    In module 'CocoaAsyncSocket' imported from /Users/alperenbaskaya/AndroidStudioProjects/desio/ios/Pods/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/Classes/WebSocket.m:3:
    /Users/alperenbaskaya/AndroidStudioProjects/desio/ios/Pods/CocoaAsyncSocket/Source/GCD/GCDAsyncSocket.h:112:58: note: passing argument to parameter 'delegate' here
    - (void)setDelegate:(nullable id<GCDAsyncSocketDelegate>)delegate delegateQueue:(nullable dispatch_queue_t)delegateQueue;
                                                             ^
    /Users/alperenbaskaya/AndroidStudioProjects/desio/ios/Pods/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/Classes/WebSocket.m:171:30: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
                            NSData *requestHeaders = [aRequest messageData];
                                                      ^~~~~~~~
    /Users/alperenbaskaya/AndroidStudioProjects/desio/ios/Pods/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/Classes/WebSocket.m:218:3: warning: block implicitly retains 'self'; explicitly mention 'self'
    to indicate this is intended behavior [-Wimplicit-retain-self]
                    delegate = newDelegate;
                    ^
                    self->
    /Users/alperenbaskaya/AndroidStudioProjects/desio/ios/Pods/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/Classes/WebSocket.m:237:7: warning: block implicitly retains 'self'; explicitly mention 'self'
    to indicate this is intended behavior [-Wimplicit-retain-self]
                    if (isStarted) return;
                        ^
                        self->
    /Users/alperenbaskaya/AndroidStudioProjects/desio/ios/Pods/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/Classes/WebSocket.m:238:3: warning: block implicitly retains 'self'; explicitly mention 'self'
    to indicate this is intended behavior [-Wimplicit-retain-self]
                    isStarted = YES;
                    ^
                    self->
    /Users/alperenbaskaya/AndroidStudioProjects/desio/ios/Pods/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/Classes/WebSocket.m:240:7: warning: block implicitly retains 'self'; explicitly mention 'self'
    to indicate this is intended behavior [-Wimplicit-retain-self]
                    if (isVersion76)
                        ^
                        self->
    /Users/alperenbaskaya/AndroidStudioProjects/desio/ios/Pods/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/Classes/WebSocket.m:263:4: warning: block implicitly retains 'self'; explicitly mention 'self'
    to indicate this is intended behavior [-Wimplicit-retain-self]
                    [asyncSocket disconnect];
                     ^
                     self->
    /Users/alperenbaskaya/AndroidStudioProjects/desio/ios/Pods/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/Classes/WebSocket.m:414:21: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
                    NSString *temp = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseHeaders encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /Users/alperenbaskaya/AndroidStudioProjects/desio/ios/Pods/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/Classes/WebSocket.m:496:19: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
                    NSString *s1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:d1 encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /Users/alperenbaskaya/AndroidStudioProjects/desio/ios/Pods/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/Classes/WebSocket.m:39:20: warning: unused function 'WS_OP_IS_FINAL_FRAGMENT'
    [-Wunused-function]
    static inline BOOL WS_OP_IS_FINAL_FRAGMENT(UInt8 frame)
                       ^
    11 warnings generated.
    /Users/alperenbaskaya/AndroidStudioProjects/desio/ios/Pods/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/Classes/Mime/MultipartFormDataParser.m:420:73: warning: conflicting parameter types in
    implementation of 'numberOfBytesToLeavePendingWithData:length:encoding:': 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned int') vs 'int' [-Wmismatched-parameter-types]
    - (int) numberOfBytesToLeavePendingWithData:(NSData*) data length:(int) length encoding:(int) encoding {
                                                                       ~~~  ^
    /Users/alperenbaskaya/AndroidStudioProjects/desio/ios/Pods/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/Classes/Mime/MultipartFormDataParser.m:32:80: note: previous definition is here
    - (int) numberOfBytesToLeavePendingWithData:(NSData*) data length:(NSUInteger) length encoding:(int) encoding;
                                                                       ~~~~~~~~~~  ^
    1 warning generated.
    /Users/alperenbaskaya/AndroidStudioProjects/desio/ios/Pods/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/Classes/HTTPServer.m:54:58: warning: sending 'HTTPServer *__strong' to parameter of incompatible
    type 'id<GCDAsyncSocketDelegate> _Nullable'
                    asyncSocket = [[GCDAsyncSocket alloc] initWithDelegate:self delegateQueue:serverQueue];
                                                                           ^~~~
    In module 'CocoaAsyncSocket' imported from /Users/alperenbaskaya/AndroidStudioProjects/desio/ios/Pods/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/Classes/HTTPServer.m:2:
    /Users/alperenbaskaya/AndroidStudioProjects/desio/ios/Pods/CocoaAsyncSocket/Source/GCD/GCDAsyncSocket.h:90:71: note: passing argument to parameter 'aDelegate' here
    - (instancetype)initWithDelegate:(nullable id<GCDAsyncSocketDelegate>)aDelegate delegateQueue:(nullable dispatch_queue_t)dq;
                                                                          ^
    /Users/alperenbaskaya/AndroidStudioProjects/desio/ios/Pods/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/Classes/HTTPServer.m:162:3: warning: block implicitly retains 'self'; explicitly mention 'self'
    to indicate this is intended behavior [-Wimplicit-retain-self]
                    documentRoot = valueCopy;
                    ^
                    self->
                                            self->
    /Users/alperenbaskaya/AndroidStudioProjects/desio/ios/Pods/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/Classes/HTTPServer.m:387:8: warning: block implicitly retains 'self'; explicitly mention 'self'
    to indicate this is intended behavior [-Wimplicit-retain-self]
                            if (txtRecordDictionary)
                                ^
                                self->
    /Users/alperenbaskaya/AndroidStudioProjects/desio/ios/Pods/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/Classes/HTTPServer.m:388:63: warning: block implicitly retains 'self'; explicitly mention 'self'
    to indicate this is intended behavior [-Wimplicit-retain-self]
                                    txtRecordData = [NSNetService dataFromTXTRecordDictionary:txtRecordDictionary];
                                                                                              ^
                                                                                              self->
    14 warnings generated.
    /Users/alperenbaskaya/AndroidStudioProjects/desio/ios/Pods/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/Classes/HTTPConnection.m:196:28: warning: sending 'HTTPConnection *__strong' to parameter of
    incompatible type 'id<GCDAsyncSocketDelegate> _Nullable'
                    [asyncSocket setDelegate:self delegateQueue:connectionQueue];
                                             ^~~~
    In module 'CocoaAsyncSocket' imported from /Users/alperenbaskaya/AndroidStudioProjects/desio/ios/Pods/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/Classes/HTTPConnection.m:1:
    /Users/alperenbaskaya/AndroidStudioProjects/desio/ios/Pods/CocoaAsyncSocket/Source/GCD/GCDAsyncSocket.h:112:58: note: passing argument to parameter 'delegate' here
    - (void)setDelegate:(nullable id<GCDAsyncSocketDelegate>)delegate delegateQueue:(nullable dispatch_queue_t)delegateQueue;
                                                             ^
    /Users/alperenbaskaya/AndroidStudioProjects/desio/ios/Pods/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/Classes/HTTPConnection.m:571:8: warning: block implicitly retains 'self'; explicitly mention
    'self' to indicate this is intended behavior [-Wimplicit-retain-self]
                    if (!started)
                         ^
                         self->
    /Users/alperenbaskaya/AndroidStudioProjects/desio/ios/Pods/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/Classes/HTTPConnection.m:573:4: warning: block implicitly retains 'self'; explicitly mention
    'self' to indicate this is intended behavior [-Wimplicit-retain-self]
                            started = YES;
                            ^
                            self->
    /Users/alperenbaskaya/AndroidStudioProjects/desio/ios/Pods/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/Classes/HTTPConnection.m:589:4: warning: block implicitly retains 'self'; explicitly mention
    'self' to indicate this is intended behavior [-Wimplicit-retain-self]
                    [asyncSocket disconnect];
                     ^
                     self->
    /Users/alperenbaskaya/AndroidStudioProjects/desio/ios/Pods/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/Classes/HTTPConnection.m:898:23: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
                    NSData *tempData = [request messageData];
                                        ^~~~~~~
    /Users/alperenbaskaya/AndroidStudioProjects/desio/ios/Pods/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/Classes/HTTPConnection.m:2507:17: warning: block implicitly retains 'self'; explicitly mention
    'self' to indicate this is intended behavior [-Wimplicit-retain-self]
                    if (sender != httpResponse)
                                  ^
                                  self->
    /Users/alperenbaskaya/AndroidStudioProjects/desio/ios/Pods/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/Classes/HTTPConnection.m:2513:8: warning: block implicitly retains 'self'; explicitly mention
    'self' to indicate this is intended behavior [-Wimplicit-retain-self]
                    if (!sentResponseHeaders)
                         ^
                         self->
    /Users/alperenbaskaya/AndroidStudioProjects/desio/ios/Pods/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/Classes/HTTPConnection.m:2519:8: warning: block implicitly retains 'self'; explicitly mention
    'self' to indicate this is intended behavior [-Wimplicit-retain-self]
                            if (ranges == nil)
                                ^
                                self->
    /Users/alperenbaskaya/AndroidStudioProjects/desio/ios/Pods/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/Classes/HTTPConnection.m:2525:10: warning: block implicitly retains 'self'; explicitly mention
    'self' to indicate this is intended behavior [-Wimplicit-retain-self]
                                    if ([ranges count] == 1)
                                         ^
                                         self->
    /Users/alperenbaskaya/AndroidStudioProjects/desio/ios/Pods/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/Classes/HTTPConnection.m:2550:17: warning: block implicitly retains 'self'; explicitly mention
    'self' to indicate this is intended behavior [-Wimplicit-retain-self]
                    if (sender != httpResponse)
                                  ^
                                  self->
    /Users/alperenbaskaya/AndroidStudioProjects/desio/ios/Pods/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/Classes/HTTPConnection.m:2556:4: warning: block implicitly retains 'self'; explicitly mention
    'self' to indicate this is intended behavior [-Wimplicit-retain-self]
                    [asyncSocket disconnectAfterWriting];
                     ^
                     self->
    11 warnings generated.
    /Users/alperenbaskaya/AndroidStudioProjects/desio/ios/Pods/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/Classes/Responses/HTTPAsyncFileResponse.m:158:56: warning: block implicitly retains 'self';
    explicitly mention 'self' to indicate this is intended behavior [-Wimplicit-retain-self]
                    HTTPLogTrace2(@"%@: eventBlock - fd[%i]", THIS_FILE, fileFD);
                                                                         ^
                                                                         self->
    In file included from /Users/alperenbaskaya/AndroidStudioProjects/desio/ios/Pods/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/Classes/Responses/HTTPAsyncFileResponse.m:3:
    /Users/alperenbaskaya/AndroidStudioProjects/desio/ios/Pods/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/Classes/HTTPLogging.h:39:72: note: expanded from macro 'HTTPLogTrace2'
    #define HTTPLogTrace2(frmt, ...)   KTVCHSLog(HTTP_LOG_TRACE,   frmt, ##__VA_ARGS__)
                                                                           ^
    /Users/alperenbaskaya/AndroidStudioProjects/desio/ios/Pods/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/Classes/HTTPLogging.h:11:75: note: expanded from macro 'KTVCHSLog'
    #define KTVCHSLog(level, frmt, ...) [HTTPLogging log:level format:frmt, ##__VA_ARGS__]
                                                                              ^
    /Users/alperenbaskaya/AndroidStudioProjects/desio/ios/Pods/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/Classes/Responses/HTTPAsyncFileResponse.m:165:69: warning: block implicitly retains 'self';
    explicitly mention 'self' to indicate this is intended behavior [-Wimplicit-retain-self]
                    unsigned long long _bytesAvailableOnFD = dispatch_source_get_data(readSource);
                                                                                      ^
                                                                                      self->
    /Users/alperenbaskaya/AndroidStudioProjects/desio/ios/Pods/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/Classes/Responses/HTTPAsyncFileResponse.m:167:29: warning: block implicitly retains 'self';
    explicitly mention 'self' to indicate this is intended behavior [-Wimplicit-retain-self]
                    UInt64 _bytesLeftInFile = fileLength - readOffset;
                                              ^
                                              self->
    /Users/alperenbaskaya/AndroidStudioProjects/desio/ios/Pods/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/Classes/Responses/HTTPAsyncFileResponse.m:167:42: warning: block implicitly retains 'self';
    explicitly mention 'self' to indicate this is intended behavior [-Wimplicit-retain-self]
                    UInt64 _bytesLeftInFile = fileLength - readOffset;
                                                           ^
                                                           self->
    /Users/alperenbaskaya/AndroidStudioProjects/desio/ios/Pods/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/Classes/Responses/HTTPAsyncFileResponse.m:175:35: warning: block implicitly retains 'self';
    explicitly mention 'self' to indicate this is intended behavior [-Wimplicit-retain-self]
                    NSUInteger bytesLeftInRequest = readRequestLength - readBufferOffset;
                                                    ^
                                                    self->
    /Users/alperenbaskaya/AndroidStudioProjects/desio/ios/Pods/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/Classes/Responses/HTTPAsyncFileResponse.m:175:55: warning: block implicitly retains 'self';
    explicitly mention 'self' to indicate this is intended behavior [-Wimplicit-retain-self]
                    NSUInteger bytesLeftInRequest = readRequestLength - readBufferOffset;
                                                                        ^
                                                                        self->
    /Users/alperenbaskaya/AndroidStudioProjects/desio/ios/Pods/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/Classes/Responses/HTTPAsyncFileResponse.m:184:7: warning: block implicitly retains 'self';
    explicitly mention 'self' to indicate this is intended behavior [-Wimplicit-retain-self]
                    if (readBuffer == NULL || bytesToRead > (readBufferSize - readBufferOffset))
                        ^
                        self->
    /Users/alperenbaskaya/AndroidStudioProjects/desio/ios/Pods/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/Classes/Responses/HTTPAsyncFileResponse.m:184:44: warning: block implicitly retains 'self';
    explicitly mention 'self' to indicate this is intended behavior [-Wimplicit-retain-self]
                    if (readBuffer == NULL || bytesToRead > (readBufferSize - readBufferOffset))
                                                             ^
                                                             self->
    /Users/alperenbaskaya/AndroidStudioProjects/desio/ios/Pods/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/Classes/Responses/HTTPAsyncFileResponse.m:184:61: warning: block implicitly retains 'self';
    explicitly mention 'self' to indicate this is intended behavior [-Wimplicit-retain-self]
                    if (readBuffer == NULL || bytesToRead > (readBufferSize - readBufferOffset))
                                                                              ^
                                                                              self->
    /Users/alperenbaskaya/AndroidStudioProjects/desio/ios/Pods/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/Classes/Responses/HTTPAsyncFileResponse.m:186:4: warning: block implicitly retains 'self';
    explicitly mention 'self' to indicate this is intended behavior [-Wimplicit-retain-self]
                            readBufferSize = bytesToRead;
                            ^
                            self->

    /Users/alperenbaskaya/AndroidStudioProjects/desio/ios/Pods/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/Classes/Responses/HTTPAsyncFileResponse.m:189:8: warning: block implicitly retains 'self';
    explicitly mention 'self' to indicate this is intended behavior [-Wimplicit-retain-self]
                            if (readBuffer == NULL)
                                ^
                                self->
    /Users/alperenbaskaya/AndroidStudioProjects/desio/ios/Pods/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/Classes/Responses/HTTPAsyncFileResponse.m:204:25: warning: block implicitly retains 'self';
    explicitly mention 'self' to indicate this is intended behavior [-Wimplicit-retain-self]
                    ssize_t result = read(fileFD, readBuffer + readBufferOffset, (size_t)bytesToRead);
 
 rojects/desio/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported
    deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'Flutter' from project 'Pods')

Could not build the application for the simulator.
```

Flutter doctor;

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.1, on macOS 11.2.1 20D74 darwin-arm, locale tr-TR)
    • Flutter version 2.2.1 at /Users/alperenbaskaya/Desktop/flutter
    • Framework revision 02c026b03c (4 days ago), 2021-05-27 12:24:44 -0700
    • Engine revision 0fdb562ac8
    • Dart version 2.13.1

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/alperenbaskaya/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 12.5, Build version 12E262
    • CocoaPods version 1.10.1

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • iPhone 8 Plus (mobile) • 971548E6-9EDD-42FD-84E8-8DDBFFC2CAB7 • ios            • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-14-5 (simulator)
    • macOS (desktop)        • macos                                • darwin-arm64   • macOS 11.2.1 20D74 darwin-arm
    • Chrome (web)           • chrome                               • web-javascript • Google Chrome 90.0.4430.212

• No issues found!
```

[image: Xcode]

podfile;

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '10.0'


# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end

end
```