# M1 Mac with Xcode 12.5 never runs Flutter Project

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, apple-m1

I am using flutter Flutter 2.2.1 • channel stable •  and Xcode 12.5 on my macOS BigSur 11.4 M1 Mac, I was using indeed. I have got lots of different error which are related different issues. I have done all the thing suggested in old repos but nothing changed. I am real stuck for 1 week.
I think it tries to build for macOS at the same time, but couldn't get how to resolve it.

May anybody help me to fix it? I am sharing links of my old 2 repos in this week. Please help, I am about to give up flutter dev.
Thanks for now, hope you help

[m1macerror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67797025/m1-mac-xcode-build-done-then-failed-flutter-project-apple-silicon)
[firstreo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67779576/flutter-xcode-build-error-when-i-open-a-downloaded-project)

**Edit**
Even in demo app of flutter it gives lots of warning.
[image: flutter_demo_app]

Comment: Update flutter to latest version, they build flutter project, only after run the app using Xcode.

Comment: Sorry to give wrong info. I have already upgraded to version 2.2.1 stable.

Comment: @MidhunMP edited repo.

Comment: Did you run flutter build?

Comment: Although flutter on android studio doesnt run at all, how could I build it? When I tap run In android studio fails

Comment: What is the error message you are getting? You can type flutter build in command line to build it https://flutter.dev/docs/reference/flutter-cli

Answer (score 1):

This happens when Cocoapods didn't setted correctly can you share your setup steps for Cocoapods. It should be done on Rosetta terminal or with Rosetta prefixed commands.

1. Open any terminal with Rosetta
2. Run `sudo gem install cocoapods`
3. Run `sudo gem install ffi`
4. Run `pod repo update`
5. Remove your ios/PodFile.lock and ios/Pods files/folders
6. Re-run your flutter project

Let me know if you encounter other issues.